# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException Java

Tags: java, swing, null, jframe, joptionpane

I keep getting this error in my console, however there's no error in my coding when I look over it. It also keeps opening up the exact same JOptionPanes when I don't want it to open up. After the loops supposedly finish, the JOptionPane reopens and goes through asking the user to input values for the Bingo Card. However, it still fills and makes a BingoCard after the first JOptionPane loops are done.

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.computeIntersection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
at day1.example.BingoCard.paintComponent(BingoCard.java:22)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
at day1.example.BingoCard.paintComponent(BingoCard.java:22)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at day1.example.BingoCard.paintComponent(BingoCard.java:27)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
at day1.example.BingoCard.paintComponent(BingoCard.java:22)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my coding

```
package BingoPackage;


import javax.swing.JComponent;


import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.*;



public class BingoCard extends JComponent {


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     {
        //Recover Graphics



        int BValues []= new int [5];
        int IValues []= new int [5];
        int NValues []= new int [4];
        int GValues []= new int [5];
        int OValues []= new int [5];
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," We will now guide you in making your very own Bingo Card");
        for (int B = 0; B<BValues.length; B++)
        {
        String BVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter 5 different numbers"+ "\n" + "that are in the range of 1-15");
        BValues[B]=Integer.parseInt(BVal);
        if (BValues[B]<1 || BValues[B]>15)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        }
        int B1 = BValues [0];
        int B2 = BValues [1];
        int B3 = BValues [2];
        int B4 = BValues [3];
        int B5 = BValues [4];
        if (B1==B2 || B1==B3 || B1== B4 || B1==B5 || B2==B3 || B2== B4|| B2==B5 || B3== B4 || B3== B5 || B4==B5)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        for (int I = 0; I<IValues.length; I++)
        {
        String IVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter 5 different numbers"+ "\n" + "that are in the range of 16-30");
        IValues[I]=Integer.parseInt(IVal);
        if (IValues[I]<16 || IValues[I]>30)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        }
        int I1 = IValues [0];
        int I2 = IValues [1];
        int I3 = IValues [2];
        int I4 = IValues [3];
        int I5 = IValues [4];
        if (I1==I2 || I1==I3 || I1== I4 || I1==I5 || I2==I3 || I2== I4|| I2==I5 || I3== I4 || I3== I5 || I4==I5)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        for (int N = 0; N<NValues.length; N++)
        {
        String NVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter 4 different numbers"+ "\n" + "that are in the range of 31-45");
        NValues[N]=Integer.parseInt(NVal);
        if (NValues[N]<31 || NValues[N]>45)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        }
        int N1 = NValues [0];
        int N2 = NValues [1];
        int N3 = NValues [2];
        int N4 = NValues [3];
        if (N1==N2 || N1==N3 || N1== N4 || N2==N3 || N2== N4|| N3== N4)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        for (int G = 0; G<GValues.length; G++)
        {
        String GVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter 5 different numbers"+ "\n" + "that are in the range of 46-60");
        GValues[G]=Integer.parseInt(GVal);
        if (GValues[G]<46 || GValues[G]>60)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        }
        int G1 = GValues [0];
        int G2 = GValues [1];
        int G3 = GValues [2];
        int G4 = GValues [3];
        int G5 = GValues [4];
        if (G1==G2 || G1==G3 || G1== I4 || G1==G5 || G2==G3 || G2== G4|| G2==G5 || G3== G4 || G3== G5 || G4==G5)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        for (int O = 0; O<OValues.length; O++)
        {
        String OVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter 5 different numbers"+ "\n" + "that are in the range of 61-75");
        OValues[O]=Integer.parseInt(OVal);
        if (OValues[O]<61 || OValues[O]>75)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        }
        int O1 = OValues [0];
        int O2 = OValues [1];
        int O3 = OValues [2];
        int O4 = OValues [3];
        int O5 = OValues [4];
        if (O1==O2 || O1==O3 || O1== O4 || O1==O5 || O2==O3 || O2== O4|| O2==O5 || O3== O4 || O3== O5 || O4==O5)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }


        Graphics2D g3 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g3.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Font bingoFont = new Font ("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN,69);
        g3.setFont(bingoFont);

        Rectangle bingosign = new Rectangle (75,10, 500, 75);
        g3.draw(bingosign);
        g3.drawString ("B   I   N  G  O", 110, 70);

        Rectangle B1Box = new Rectangle (75, 85, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(B1Box);

        Rectangle B2Box = new Rectangle (75, 185, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(B2Box);

        Rectangle B3Box = new Rectangle (75, 285, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(B3Box);

        Rectangle B4Box = new Rectangle (75, 385, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(B4Box);

        Rectangle B5Box = new Rectangle (75, 485, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(B5Box);

        Rectangle I1Box = new Rectangle (175, 85, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(I1Box);

        Rectangle I2Box = new Rectangle (175, 185, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(I2Box);

        Rectangle I3Box = new Rectangle (175, 285, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(I3Box);

        Rectangle I4Box = new Rectangle (175, 385, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(I4Box);

        Rectangle I5Box = new Rectangle (175, 485, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(I5Box);

        Rectangle N1Box = new Rectangle (275, 85, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(N1Box);

        Rectangle N2Box = new Rectangle (275, 185, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(N2Box);

        Rectangle N3Box = new Rectangle (275, 285, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(N3Box);

        Rectangle N4Box = new Rectangle (275, 385, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(N4Box);

        Rectangle N5Box = new Rectangle (275, 485, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(N5Box);

        Rectangle G1Box = new Rectangle (375, 85, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(G1Box);

        Rectangle G2Box = new Rectangle (375, 185, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(G2Box);

        Rectangle G3Box = new Rectangle (375, 285, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(G3Box);

        Rectangle G4Box = new Rectangle (375, 385, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(G4Box);

        Rectangle G5Box = new Rectangle (375, 485, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(G5Box);

        Rectangle O1Box = new Rectangle (475, 85, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(O1Box);

        Rectangle O2Box = new Rectangle (475, 185, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(O2Box);

        Rectangle O3Box = new Rectangle (475, 285, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(O3Box);

        Rectangle O4Box= new Rectangle (475, 385, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(O4Box);

        Rectangle O5Box = new Rectangle (475, 485, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(O5Box);

        g3.setColor(Color.RED);
        g3.fill(N3Box);

        g3.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        String B1String = String.valueOf(B1);
        String B2String = String.valueOf(B2);
        String B3String = String.valueOf(B3);
        String B4String = String.valueOf(B4);
        String B5String = String.valueOf(B5);
        String I1String = String.valueOf(I1);
        String I2String = String.valueOf(I2);
        String I3String = String.valueOf(I3);
        String I4String = String.valueOf(I4);
        String I5String = String.valueOf(I5);
        String N1String = String.valueOf(N1);
        String N2String = String.valueOf(N2);
        String N3String = String.valueOf(N3);
        String N4String = String.valueOf(N4);
        String G1String = String.valueOf(G1);
        String G2String = String.valueOf(G2);
        String G3String = String.valueOf(G3);
        String G4String = String.valueOf(G4);
        String G5String = String.valueOf(G5);
        String O1String = String.valueOf(O1);
        String O2String = String.valueOf(O2);
        String O3String = String.valueOf(O3);
        String O4String = String.valueOf(O4);
        String O5String = String.valueOf(O5);

        g3.drawString(B1String, 90, 160);
        g3.drawString(B2String, 90, 260);
        g3.drawString(B3String, 90, 360);
        g3.drawString(B4String, 90, 460);
        g3.drawString(B5String, 90, 560);
        g3.drawString(I1String, 190, 160);
        g3.drawString(I2String, 190, 260);
        g3.drawString(I3String, 190, 360);
        g3.drawString(I4String, 190, 460);
        g3.drawString(I5String, 190, 560);
        g3.drawString(N1String, 290, 160);
        g3.drawString(N2String, 290, 260);
        g3.drawString(N3String, 290, 460);
        g3.drawString(N4String, 290, 560);
        g3.drawString(G1String, 390, 160);
        g3.drawString(G2String, 390, 260);
        g3.drawString(G3String, 390, 360);
        g3.drawString(G4String, 390, 460);
        g3.drawString(G5String, 390, 560);
        g3.drawString(O1String, 490, 160);
        g3.drawString(O2String, 490, 260);
        g3.drawString(O3String, 490, 360);
        g3.drawString(O4String, 490, 460);
        g3.drawString(O5String, 490, 560);


    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    Font freeSpaceFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN,16);
    g2.setFont(freeSpaceFont);
    g2.drawString("Free", 305, 330);
    g2.drawString("Space", 300, 350);


     }
}
```

What is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seem you are getting null entry at line

```
String BVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter 5 different numbers"+ "\n" + "that are in the range of 1-15");
```

So line

```
 BValues[B]=Integer.parseInt(BVal);
is causing the exception.
```

Trace what you are getting BVal as input.

Important: Always use validation while taking input from user.

**Update:**
I checked further, you are taking input in multiple places. Put validation wherever needed

[validation reference](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=5)